# Calling Partial View From Controller and get the return to variable in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Can I call a partial view from controller and get the return of it and save to above mentioned controller's variable.

Ex: string resultHtml = PartialView("_partialViewName", Model);

Please explain me this